# odataclient.query is not a function in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have function in my application which returns the student details by making an ODATA call.
However the below code returns "this.edmOdataClient.query is not a function" error.
value of Id that is passed to the function is
4B199,9h7dH,ATC3S,fDB5Y,h33Ny,kousB,lTibg,nuGM

Below is my code snippet

```
async getStudent(Id) {
    
        try {
            if (Id != undefined) {
                let index: number;
                for (index = 0; index < Id.length; index++) {
                    const element = Id[index];
                    console.log("ELEMENT" +element);
                    this.student = await this.OdataClient.get<any>
                        (
                            this.edmOdataClient
                                .query(`CD_STUDENT`)
                                .filter(new FilterClause("SECTION").eq("A"))
                                .andFilter(new FilterClause("ID").eq(element))
                                .select(["NAME", "GRADE"])
                                .orderBy("ID")
                                ).then(result => result.value[0])
                }
            }
            return this.student;
        }
        catch (error) {
            logger.info(error.message)
            return error;
        }
```

Also is there a way to check result.value.length?
When am trying to do so am getting error that result is undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`this` is only something you can call if your function belongs to a class (also note that arrow functions dont respond to `this` unless you bind the function)

```js
const externalFunc = () => {
  console.log('external func')
}

class MyClass {
  constructor () {
    this.externalFunc = externalFunc.bind(this)
  }

  myFuncOne () {
    console.log('func one')
  }
  
  myFuncTwo () {
    console.log('func two')
    this.myFuncOne()
  }
}

const klass = new MyClass()
klass.myFuncTwo()
// => func two
// => func one

klass.externalFunc()
// => external func
```

in your code, essentially the error is saying that `getStudent` is unable to reach `edmOdataClient` because its not bound to `this`

whatever class your code is running within doesnt have access to `edmOdataClient`

Comment: Agreed....such a small mistake which I overlooked...Muck thanks!

Comment: Also is there a way I could check the value of length of result?

Comment: unfortunately i've never interacted much with odata API's much, you would have to console.log the results and see what you can find 